# Remove specific array in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, splice

I need to remove a line using for loop, for some reason splice didn't work..

The code is

```
for (let course of department_arr) {

  for (let i in new_assignment_ls) {
    if (course.CourseName == new_assignment_ls[i][3] &&
      course.Semester == new_assignment_ls[i][4].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ') &&
      course.Route == new_assignment_ls[i][5].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')) { // check courses are equal to submitted

      dataHtml += `<tr class='accordion' id="accordion" onclick="newAssign(this)"><td>${new_assignment_ls[i][0]}</td><td>${new_assignment_ls[i][1]}</td><td>${new_assignment_ls[i][2]}</td><td>${course.Year}</td><td>${course.Semester}</td><td>${course.Route}</td><td>${course.CourseName}</td></tr>`;
      department_arr.splice(course, course);

    }
  }

  dataHtml += `<tr class='accordion' id="accordion" onclick="newAssign(this)"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>${course.Year}</td><td>${course.Semester}</td><td>${course.Route}</td><td>${course.CourseName}</td></tr>`;
}
```

the if works good and the output is good but for some reason it prints me the outcome of the if + the outcome in the else for the same line.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: I think your splice call is invalid.  Should be splice(course, indexPositionToRemove);  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score -1):

nvm I've managed to solve the issue.
I had an issue with the splice and I called back the array after the splice and it seems to work.

10x

Comment: Can you please update with fixed code sample.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).